# How to attach a plugin license to a CMS license?

Tags: plugins, license, craft-id

I have a Craft license that is not attached to a Craft CMS license and cannot figure out where/how to attach it to one in my Craft ID account so that I can use it in a Craft CMS installation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to install the plugin on whatever site you want to associate with it - and then enter the license for it under `Settings > Plugins`.